# How to make a SVG element only response to certain event but pass other event down to lower layers in D3 or jQuery

Tags: jquery, events, d3.js

All:

I am pretty new to D3 and jQuery event handling.

Right now:

```
var svg = d3.select("body svg")
                    .style("border", function(){
                        return "1px solid black";   
                    })
                    .attr("width", 400)
                    .attr("height", 400);


var btm = svg.append("g")
                .attr("transform", function(){
                    return "translate(100,100)";
                })
                .append("rect")
                .attr("width", 100)
                .attr("height", 100)
                .style("fill", "tomato");

btm.on("mousedown", function(){
    console.log("tomato mousedown");
});


btm.on("mouseup", function(){
    console.log("tomato mouseup");
});

var bup = svg.append("g")
                .attr("transform", function(){
                    return "translate(150,150)";
                })
                .append("rect")
                .attr("width", 100)
                .attr("height", 100)
                .style("fill", "lightseagreen");
bup.on("mousedown", function(){
    console.log("seagreen mousedown");
    d3.select(this).style("pointer-events", "none");
});
```

The code make the upper level(the seagreen rect) respond to mouse down, and disable itself to respond and let all events passed to lower tomato red rect)

what I want to do is let the **seagreen rect only respond to mouseover**, but let the **tomato red  rect respond to mousedown**(but still keep the green one on top of tomato red one).

I checked [the pointer-events page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events), but have no idea which one or ones to use to configure them, could anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Based on what you describe, don't you mean `bup.on("mouseover", function()` instead of `mousedown`? The way you have it, as `mousedown` suggests that you expect to be able to receive the `mouseup` that follows— within the same click interaction — from `btm`. That might not ever work. Would have to be tested. This stuff, especially  with `pointer-events` is kind of fragile and prone to variance between browsers. So even if it's doable, you'll want to check it in various browsers.

Comment: @meetamit Thanks for help. But NO, I do mean the mouseover event on bup. The scenario is: The bup is a layer to detect mouse hover event, and when I mouse down, I hope the mouse down can penetrate the bup and passed to btm,  the btm need to respond to it.